# Elixir skip operator instead of another message?

Tags: elixir

I am wondering how I can skip to the end of this function after 3_000 milliseconds but without any other printed message on screen or calling other functions or sending further messages.

```
defmodule ExampleModule do

    def main do
        Process.send_after(self(), :hello, 2_000)
        send self(), :hello_again
        next()
    end

    def next do
        receive do
            :hello -> IO.puts("Received hello") 
            :hello_again -> IO.puts("Received hello_again")
            after 3_000 -> <SKIP to the very end without recursion>
       end 
        next()
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no construct like `goto` or `return` in Elixir. Here are two ways you can solve this:

1. Explicitly call `next()` in the branches you want to continue recursing:

   ```
   def next do
     receive do
       :hello ->
         IO.puts("Received hello") 
         next()
       :hello_again ->
         IO.puts("Received hello_again")
         next()
       after 3_000 ->
         :ok
     end 
   end
   ```
2. Store the value of the receive expression and call `next()` based on that:

   ```
   def next do
     continue = receive do
       :hello ->
         IO.puts("Received hello") 
         true
       :hello_again ->
         IO.puts("Received hello_again")
         true
       after 3_000 ->
         false
     end 
     if continue, do: next()
   end
   ```